# Adding numbers from an if-statement that only follow the requirement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this bit of code for an if statement. What I'm trying to do is add all number 3s that appear in a random roll of five die.

For example, I roll: 5 5 2 3 3

6 is meant to print out.

Currently, if a 3 appears, it adds all of the rolls. I'm trying to understand how to isolate only the threes to be added. Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!

```
if (die1 == 3 || die2 == 3 || die3 == 3 || die4 == 3 || die5 == 3 ) {
    int addThree;
    addThree = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4 + die5;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(addThree);
}
```

Comment: You should look into `ArrayList` for the dice rather then 6 individual vars

Comment: you are adding everything `addThree = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4 + die5;` instead have seperate if statements and add the compared die value

Comment: Do you want to get a single number (like 9) if there were only three 3s, or do you want to get the string "3 3 3" ?

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup:

```
int total = 0;

if(die1 == 3) total += die1;
if(die2 == 3) total += die2;
if(die3 == 3) total += die3;
if(die4 == 3) total += die4;
if(die5 == 3) total += die5;
```

I would put the die into a `List` and do the following:

```
List<Integer> dice = new ArrayList<>();
dice.add(die1);
dice.add(die2);
dice.add(die3);
dice.add(die4);
dice.add(die5);

total = 0;
for(Integer die : dice) {
  if(die == 3) total += die;
}
```

Comment: How would you make it more efficient Andrew?

Comment: @SamuelFrench You could put it into a data structure, then loop. The answer is also encouraging bad practice: duplicating code...

Comment: While you are right it would probably be more efficient to add it to a list or set or whatever and loop, you are making assumptions with information you don't have. What if he is the consumer of an API that gives them back as individual variables? And you can't say "the API is bad" :)

Comment: I know he just changed the answer, and the old answer was bad practice.

Adding it to a data structure and looping through the structure to add the numbers would be much cleaner and more maintainable, but I don't see how that would be more efficient because each iteration of the loop would do an if statement to see if the element is 3, and then add, which is the same as he had before but it was inlined.

Comment: In the second answer, it's actually slower because he first creates a new data structure (object creation) and then iterates through it.

He still does the same logic with an extra object creation and then whatever overhead using an additional control structure causes.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, I put in some extra code to display the result and fill the ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> dice = new ArrayList<>();

    dice.add(1);
    dice.add(2);
    dice.add(4);
    dice.add(3);
    dice.add(3);

    int addThree = 0;

    for (Integer die : dice) {
        if (die == 3) {
            addThree += 3;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(addThree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
 List<Integer>numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
 numbers.add(5);
 numbers.add(4);
 numbers.add(3);
 numbers.add(3);
 numbers.add(3);
 System.out.println(3*Collections.frequency(numbers, 3));
```